# Is there anyway that I can mark a test case passed or failed from within the test case itself

Tags: testing, azure-devops, manual

If I am withing a test case in VSTS is there any way I can mark this test "Passed" or "Failed" without going back out to the Test Hub?

Answer (score 0):

No, we cannot mark the outcome to "`Passed`" or "`Failed`" within test case itself.

`Test case` is a work item type, a test case is just a work item and the work item itself doesn't have a field with the value "`Passed`" or "`Failed`".

The outcome "`Passed`" or "`Failed`" is just for test result, so you have to make a test run to pass or fail the test case. You can check that a new test run will be generated when you mark a test case to `passed` or `failed` in Test Hub. (Just check that under Test --> Runs)